# unable to find activity

Tags: android

I have two Activity in my project.One is MainActivity and another is upload File.
On button click it gives me error like: unable to find activity.
This is code where i declared it in  manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".UploadFile"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
    >
</activity>
```

This is code by where i am calling uploadfile activity:

```
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                       {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,UploadFIle.class);
                startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Change to `Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,UploadFile.class);` typo error `UploadFile` not `UploadFIle`

Answer (score 4):

`Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,UploadFIle.class);` Is this a typo? Notice `FIle`.

Answer (score 1):

you have UploadFIle in Code but UploadFile in manifest UploadFIle vs UploadFile

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your activitiess are declared in the manifest.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".UploadFile"
              android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <intent-filter>
          <category android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: this does not answer the quesion. there is a typo error. Activity is already declared in manifest which is posted in the question. The error is its `UploadFile` not `UploadFIle`